# What does the ending to this する　conjugation mean してんなぁ?

Tags: explanatory-の

Here is my sentence なんか俺 体力低下してんなぁ meaning "I feel like I am getting weaker." 低下 means to fall/decline and it is a noun and can be used as a suru verb. It seems suru is in it's te form here, my guess is because it's describing an ongoing state and I believe the ん in してんなぁ is the "explanatory" ~ んです. If that is the case, what purpose does the なぁ have at the end of this statement and what effect does having this explanatory statement provide instead of just saying なんか俺 体力低下して. The following sentence is 手がふるえる and this is from Yotsuba (1st chapter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

～してんなぁ is a contraction of ～してるなぁ (which in itself is a contraction of ～しているなぁ, as you probably know). る sometimes becomes ん before certain consonants.

Comment: Ahh makes sense. Thank you. What might the なぁ be then? Could it be as if you were thinking out loud or saying it to yourself as much as to the other person?

Comment: @UCProgrammer な or なぁ is a sentence-final particle similar to ね in some ways. I would advise you to do some research of your own. I don't feel qualified to explain in detail.